# How does the Info vernacular command work?

Tags: coq

Suppose I have the following simple lemma and I want to get information about `split`.

```
Lemma and_prop : forall (P : Prop) (Q : Prop),
  P -> Q -> P /\ Q.
Proof.
  intros P Q HP HQ. 
  Info 100 split.
```

which outputs

```
simple refine ?X10@{__:=P; __:=Q; __:=HP; __:=HQ}
```

Can someone please explain what this means and why I need a natural number for Info?

Comment: [Here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:cmd.Info) is the reference for the Info command in the Coq documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You link to [the documentation of `Info`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:cmd.Info) in the comment on your question, but don't say what's confusing about the manual:

> The number natural is the unfolding level of tactics in the trace. At level 0, the trace contains a sequence of tactics in the actual script, at level 1, the trace will be the concatenation of the traces of these tactics, etc…

The `Info` vernacular is not very useful for built-in tactics (such as `split`), which are implemented in OCaml plugins and thus don't really have an Ltac trace.  It's even less useful for tactics like `apply`, which still use the legacy OCaml tactic interface: `Info 1 apply conj` on emits nothing (and I've reported this as [bug #15223](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/15223) just now).  Unfortunately, `split` and `constructor` suffer from the same problem of not telling the user what constructor was applied; I've reported this as [bug #15224](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/15224) just now.

That said, `simple refine` is sort-of the basic primitive building block of tactics.  It's a variant of [the `refine` tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.refine) which allows users to partially fill in a proof term.  Here's it's just saying that you're partially filling in the proof term with the evar `?X10` where its four unnamed context variables are filled with `P`, `Q`, `HP`, and `HQ`.  This is not very helpful here, but here are some more useful outputs of `Info`:

```
Lemma and_prop : forall (P : Prop) (Q : Prop),
  P -> Q -> P /\ Q.
Proof.
  Info 2 refine (fun P Q => _).
  (* simple refine fun P Q : Prop => ?X4@{__:=P; __:=Q};simple refine ?X5@{__:=P; __:=Q};shelve_unifiable *)
```

The interesting one here is `simple refine fun P Q : Prop => ?X4@{...}`, where you can see the function I put in.

In the following, you can see how each additional level of info peels back a layer of tactic indirection, and how the final level displays the separate `simple refine`s for introducing each variable:

```
Ltac split' := split.
Ltac split'' := split'.
Ltac split''' := split''.

Lemma and_prop : forall (P : Prop) (Q : Prop),
  P -> Q -> P /\ Q.
Proof.
  Info 0 split'''. (* split''' *) Undo.
  Info 1 split'''. (* split'' *) Undo.
  Info 2 split'''. (* split' *) Undo.
  Info 3 split'''. (* split *) Undo.
  Info 4 split'''. (* <ltac_plugin::split@0> *) Undo.
  Info 5 split'''. (* <ltac_plugin::split@0>simple refine ?X2;simple refine fun P : Prop => ?X3@{__:=P};
simple refine fun Q : Prop => ?X4@{__:=P; __:=Q};
simple refine fun H : P => ?X5@{__:=P; __:=Q; __:=H};simple refine fun H0 : Q => ?X6@{__:=P; __:=Q; __:=H; __:=H0} *) Undo.
```

Comment: My question may have been ill-posed. I originally posted it because "info" is a bit overloaded of a term and so was hard to Google. I eventually did find it, hence my first comment. I'm ultimately trying to make Coq resources more search-able. Your answer goes into more depth and provides more examples than the documentation.